# Flow typing error : Cannot call dispatch with object literal bound to action because:

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype, redux-thunk

I am getting the following error in Flow:

Cannot call dispatch with object literal bound to action because:

• Either string literal REMOVE_FROM_CART [1] is incompatible with string literal ADD_TO_CART [2] in property type.

• Or string literal ADD_TO_CART [1] is incompatible with string literal REMOVE_FROM_CART [3] in property type.

• Or string literal ADD_TO_CART [1] is incompatible with string literal INCREMENT [4] in property type.

• Or string literal ADD_TO_CART [1] is incompatible with string literal DECREMENT [5] in property type.

• Or string literal ADD_TO_CART [1] is incompatible with string literal DISPLAY_PRODUCT_DETAIL [6] in property type.

> **I am getting error in the dispatch function  marked as ** dispatch ** below**

```
export const updateCart = (id: number, type: ProductActionsType) => {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<ProductActionsReturnTypes>) => {
       **dispatch({ type, payload: id });**
       dispatch({ type: UPDATE_TOTALS });
     };
 };
```

**File: constants.js**

```
export const FETCH_ITEMS = "FETCH_ITEMS";
export const ADD_TO_CART: "ADD_TO_CART" = "ADD_TO_CART";
export const REMOVE_FROM_CART: "REMOVE_FROM_CART" = "REMOVE_FROM_CART";
export const DISPLAY_PRODUCT_DETAIL: "DISPLAY_PRODUCT_DETAIL" =
  "DISPLAY_PRODUCT_DETAIL";
export const INCREMENT: "INCREMENT" = "INCREMENT";
export const DECREMENT: "DECREMENT" = "DECREMENT";
export const UPDATE_TOTALS: "UPDATE_TOTALS" = "UPDATE_TOTALS";
export const CLEAR_CART: "CLEAR_CART" = "CLEAR_CART";
export const OPEN_MODAL: "OPEN_MODAL" = "OPEN_MODAL";
export const CLOSE_MODAL: "CLOSE_MODAL" = "CLOSE_MODAL";
```

**File: src/types/index.js**

```
export type ClearCartActionType = {|
type: typeof CLEAR_CART
|};

type AddToCartActionType = {|
type: typeof ADD_TO_CART,
payload: number
|};

type RemoveFromCartActionType = {|
type: typeof REMOVE_FROM_CART,
payload: number
|};

export type DisplayProductDetailAction = {|
type: typeof DISPLAY_PRODUCT_DETAIL,
payload: number
|};

type IncrementActionType = {|
type: typeof INCREMENT,
payload: number
|};

type DecrementActionType = {|
type: typeof DECREMENT,
payload: number
|};

export type UpdateTotalsActionType = {|
type: typeof UPDATE_TOTALS
|};

export type ModalPayloadType = {|
id: number,
products: Array<ProductType>
|};

export type ProductActionsType =
| typeof ADD_TO_CART
| typeof REMOVE_FROM_CART
| typeof INCREMENT
| typeof DECREMENT
| typeof UPDATE_TOTALS
| typeof DISPLAY_PRODUCT_DETAIL
| typeof CLEAR_CART;

export type ProductActionsReturnTypes =
| AddToCartActionType
| RemoveFromCartActionType
| IncrementActionType
| DecrementActionType
| UpdateTotalsActionType
| DisplayProductDetailAction
| ClearCartActionType;
```

I am stuck with this. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Flow link to reproduce the issue
[link](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiBLAzmAhjAYwAsBBABQEkAeEgPjgF44AKXAmDCAOwC44SAlI3okA3AChQkWAmSpMOfMRp8A3rJR8AVABo4AOkNwAvvSYK8hUpRq1RcSeGjwC3LPABiAUQAqAYQAJAH0KHy8AWQBlRjgAIm9-YNCIyNiJKWc4Vy53fjQ0IJ8AeSC-EgAlHz5YknzCkrLK2JiauuLSip80x2kXN3hyiKKANS8gj3Ki8I7K6sHwkbGJqZmulvnF8cnpxq70pxls3LQKSLIAGRIATSCySbQAVT8fILRfEgpz6pOzy5u7oqPZ6vd6fZoMcRwOI-C7XW73J4vN4+D7nboZQ79OAUAByfnmXhxVTiuPxEUJayYsVJBKJ6IOfRy8DeZPCFO+XlZFPB0M5tL2PUyR3gDzIaBIYXqKPOkWqovFkuK0tSLXlErGSpIMvpvSyWL85y8FVW1QNRvKqx5sTNxt2OqFWKKZEJQQW4q+cSdLrdWqtXpxrsBvv2uuFcANRUiYx9Hut50j0aDaJaEajgfd3UFMiQKDgZCgEAAJgBXdg+OQxVQAH0hcAwhb4XGLAFsAEbAKA6WscGAAG2AfHcUAwXAA5l2oRhm6PBzBh2OJ3AwMOCAO4E22x3F65m3guIhZ-Px7WRwAzCCHkfHydcPy4WB8VsQCD93BcbcQYtcGCNlvtzvdhAMC4L2v6blA4hVsYEjiFm8A5qgfivlAd6wCQ7CcFw5a5kw1biAhfAIRAp7hoatqdJB0GwQh-CFoWPgQKhMDoRw3DYaguE1gRGjAMReQFO0uxdngiC9hAuANuuf4dpRME0eUwDNhAABuwAeAWzZMSxmHsZWXFyIRch8RsoxbCsQniCJYkSWB-6ybBGLwRWFi9rgiD5kWpYwGgwDARgvbadwen4QZPF8TCfzwoCiIgiinzCW51mSRudlQXJFYUFwBBQIpwDfoFWEVpxIWaGFJE0uSRIJaJ4nJdJEFpdRznANluX5RhbFFXAeHcURJEsvy1VJbZMmNXBPFwA8YCFvgwAMcBvZYAVunFb1RkkWqipFMq9njTR4RFiBZCJbVK3dTW9YjQBy6eewWB8CQUBQG5VAeSWZZyLQu2ORNb1eQVWArZBZX8fUqzA31cAmUs2zg1WIMVWyRIQ+t6B8pVPgoygfGbRq21apEWO8f1pywv8CLAsiqJE3xNoWrsME-TRf3sADCkwMWUCFSgWCMMDJB0QxWkddzwDAwpSmqepECafezEi+xwOZa1zZ5fLrGi8DPkq2ry1yMDU0zTAc1ASBS0K-r8MuW5LPeb5uD+QVwNIcA97Cxr7EweNYbFtNs1MTEzCXVJ4F6NxtsA+xQgMPQqi1lCOUc1zLCFtgljEHwFhKEQr0Fu96uYVg7Oc6LWC0NHsfx1CUKp4oVjMOoCF6FZtV8PWJgCBI1fd7X6dEA3PF8LjUoEx3Xfd1RJiiEAA)

Comment: It will be much easier for other people to diagnose the issue if you create a minimal reproducing case on the [try flow](https://flow.org/try/) page.

Comment: I am unable to share the case in the comment. It says the text is too long. Hence I have updated the case in the question itself at the end. Please check. @josephjnk

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a proper answer so much as it is an alternative. I was unable to get your example working and generally find working with object types and spreads in Flow complicated, so here is how I would solve the problem. This is a simplified example, including just enough of the actions to show the style being used.

```js
type Dispatch<A, B> = A => B;

class AddToCartAction {
  payload: number;
  constructor(payload: number) {
    this.payload = payload;
  }
}

class RemoveFromCartAction {
  payload: number;
  constructor(payload: number) {
    this.payload = payload;
  }
}

class UpdateTotalsAction {}

/*
 * I removed the additional type annotations from the constants here,
 * and put their literal values in ProductActionsType instead. While
 * this adds some duplication, it works alongside Flow better. If the
 * annotations are used on the constants, and anyone forgets to add one
 * to a new constant, then ProductActionsType will have its type inferred
 * as "string", thus invisibly reducing type safety by allowing more
 * inputs than desired. By putting the literal strings in both the
 * constants and the types, the type system will catch you if you make
 * a typo, and it becomes more clear what is allowed as a
 * ProductActionsType.
 */
export const ADD_TO_CART = "ADD_TO_CART";
export const REMOVE_FROM_CART = "REMOVE_FROM_CART";
export const UPDATE_TOTALS = "UPDATE_TOTALS";

export type ProductActionsType =
| "ADD_TO_CART"
| "REMOVE_FROM_CART"
| "UPDATE_TOTALS";


export type ProductActionsReturnTypes =
| AddToCartAction
| RemoveFromCartAction
| UpdateTotalsAction;

export const updateCart = (id: number, type: ProductActionsType) => {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<ProductActionsReturnTypes, void>) => {
        const action =
              type === "ADD_TO_CART"      ? new AddToCartAction(id)
        :     type === "REMOVE_FROM_CART" ? new RemoveFromCartAction(id)
        :     /* else UPDATE_TOTALS      */ new UpdateTotalsAction();
        dispatch(action);
        dispatch(new UpdateTotalsAction());
      };
 };
```

The basic idea is that, instead of using objects with a `type` field, one class is made for each type. Flow's type refinements are very, very good at handling classes, and it's easier to understand type signatures and type errors when multiple types aren't being fused into one.

The nested ternary expressions can be read as an alternative to a switch/case statement, with the added benefit that they can handle arbitrary boolean expressions in their condition. For example, I would handle actions with code like this:

```js
function handleActions(a: ProductActionTypes) {
  return a instanceof AddToCartAction      ? handleAddToCart(a.payload)
  :      a instanceof RemoveFromCartAction ? handleRemoveFromCart(a.payload)
  :      /* a is an UpdateTotalsAction    */ handleUpdateTotals();
}
```

This syntax can be seen under the "Conditional Chains" section of the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) on ternary expressions. It works well with Flow, which will know the type of `a` in each of the right-hand sides of the conditionals. Flow will even know if you forgot to test for a case, because the last conditional assumes that every other class in the `ProductActionTypes` type has been checked for already.

Hopefully this is helpful, even if it isn't exactly what you were looking for. I write all of my Flow code in this style and haven't had any really gnarly, confusing type errors since I've started doing so.

Comment: I understand why you have placed strings directly instead of constants. But repeating "ADD_TO_CART" kind of values at multiple places can lead to spelling errors right and if we try to change the name of ADD_TO_CART later , the value has to be changed at multiple places.

Comment: Fortunately this is one of the benefits of a type system. While the two locations do become coupled, Flow will ensure that they are kept in sync correctly because a type error will occur if they are different.